# Объединить все элементы списка в строку (с разделителем)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть массив данных parameters типа string.  Нужно пройтись в цикле по каждой строке в массиве и присвоить новому параметру значение строки. Есть следующий код:

```
for string in parameters:
                    glob_param, glob_param1, glob_param2, glob_param3, glob_param4 = string
                    full_data = ('%(glob_param)s %(glob_param1)s %(glob_param2)s %(glob_param3)s %(glob_param4)s'
                          % {"glob_param": glob_param, "glob_param1": glob_param1, "glob_param2": glob_param2,
                             "glob_param3": glob_param3, "glob_param4": glob_param4})
```

Проблема в том, что я каждый раз не знаю сколько параметров у меня будет в  `parameters`, и соответственно сколько нужно `glob_param`. Нужно в цикле определить необходимое количество и выполнить присваивание.

Comment: приведите небольшой пример входных данных и то, что хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: у меня есть массив данных `parameters`, которые я получаю из базы данных и вывожу на экран. Нужно переприсвоить эти данные глобальной переменной  `full_data`, чтобы потом, в другой функции я мог эти данные через  `full_data` сохранить в PDF.

Comment: Попробуйте привести в вопросе [минимальный, самодостаточный и __воспроизводимый__ пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: если `parameters` - это список (плоский / невложенный) -  `full_data = ' '.join(parameters)`

Comment: да, проверил, этот метод работает: `full_data = ''.join(parameters) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
parameters = ['parm1', 'parm2', 'parm3', 'parm4']
full_data = ' '.join(parameters)
print(full_data)
```

результат:

```
parm1 parm2 parm3 parm4
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
all_parameters = [['parm1', 'parm2', 'parm3', 'parm4'], ['parm21','parm22','parm23']]

res = ''

for parameters in all_parameters:
    res += ' ' + ' '.join(parameters)

print(res)
```

вывод:

```
 parm1 parm2 parm3 parm4 parm21 parm22 parm23
```

Comment: С этим решением появились вопросы. Если присваивание происходит один раз, то все работает хорошо. Однако у меня `parameters ` присваиваются в цикле и сразу выводятся на экран. А в глобальной `full_data` нужно накопить результат всех итераций `parameters `. И вот здесь проблема, после прохода цикла в `full_data` только последний `parameters `.

Comment: @AndrewLee, используйте += вместо =

Comment: Выводит только первый символ и падает с ошибкой: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @AndrewLee, я привел новый пример в ответе...

Comment: теперь все работает